# XSL: How can i get a tree of parent child data from xml

Tags: xml, xslt, treeview

I have the following xml structur of parents and childs and i want to create a tree in html with xsl transforming. The ancestor is the highest parent.

```
 <test>
  <id>A</id>
  <parendid></parendid>
  <ancestorid></ancestorid>
 </test>
 <test>
  <id>B</id>
  <parendid>A</parendid>
  <ancestorid>A</ancestorid>
 </test>
 <test>
  <id>C</id>
  <parendid>B</parendid>
  <ancestorid>A</ancestorid>
 </test>
 <test>
  <id>D</id>
  <parendid></parendid>
  <ancestorid></ancestorid>
 </test>
 <test>
  <id>E</id>
  <parendid>D</parendid>
  <ancestorid>D</ancestorid>
 </test>
 <test>
  <id>F</id>
  <parendid>D</parendid>
  <ancestorid>D</ancestorid>
 </test>
```

I want to have this structure.

```
 A
 +---B
 |   +---C
 D
 +---E
 +---F

 <html>
 <body>
 <div id="treeview">
    <ul>
        <li>A
            <ul>
                <li>B
                    <ul>
                        <li>C</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>D
            <ul>
                <li>E</li>
                <li>F</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm new in xsl and i need your help.

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: Your input isn't a valid XML, please correct it. From your statement it looks like you want an html output, but your expected output shows text. There is no proper explanation for how you want to achieve your output. And the most important, your tried XSLT?

Comment: This is only the structure from my xml file. And yes, the output here is text. It's should only show the output structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple implementation with html result (just for sample):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="4.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="test" use="parendid" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- for each root -->
    <xsl:for-each select="key('children', '')">
        <xsl:call-template name="traverse">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0"/>   
            <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="id"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template name="traverse">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <xsl:param name="parent"/>
    <div style="padding-left:{$level*10}">
        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
    </div>
    <!-- recursively traverse all descendants using parentid element for building parent-child link -->
    <xsl:for-each select="key('children', id)">
        <xsl:call-template name="traverse">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="id"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here key('children', '') = all elements with empty parent, i.e. "roots".

Key here is used for optimisation, because without keys performance is very bad on large xml files, due to nested for loops.

p.s. I have wrapped test nodes by root element in order to make xml well-formed.